# configure hibernate configuration file

Tags: java, hibernate

following is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect </property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="org.javabrains.koushik.dto.UserDetails"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Error I am getting is as follows

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
        SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
        SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
        Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration:  /hibernate.cfg.xml

```
Stack Trace:
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2246)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2158)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2137)
    at org.koushik.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:13)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document  : The         processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. Nested exception: The        processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2238)
... 3 more
```

I am new to Hibernate. Was following a tutorial. Got this error. Can anybody help me with this??

Comment: from stack trace it seems Hibernate configuration xml has error..please do post configuration

Comment: Google for "The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed", and you'll find the answer.

Comment: Thanks JB. Followed your suggestion, googled it and found that a white space before <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

at the beginning of your xml file.

**Edit:**(after you updated your code)

1. check if there are some blank space or other content before the `<?xml ?>`
2. check if there is a Byte Order Mark (BOM) before the `<?xml ?>` ([here](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark#remove) is a tutorial to remove it)
3. check if there is another `<?xml ?>` definition in your document

Comment: are you sure? (maybe you missed the `?`) the message says: `Error on line 1 of document`. please post your complete config

Comment: what was the problem?

Answer (score -2):

if any one get this  ***The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.*** error

Solution to this error is that
 
1.This line should be the firs line and should not leave any space before this line.